# How to restrict textbox that only allow whole numbers specifically thousands?

Tags: javascript, java

Or is it even possible to automate the typed number to specific thousand amounts only?
When the customer type an amount that is not a thousand whole number then the text/input box will automatically change it to thousand amount.

Like:

> 11111 becomes 10000
>
> 23344 becomes 20000
>
> 50003 becomes 50000

The amount to be input only should be 10000 and not ranging to 10500 or 10003. But allow 12000 or 520000.

The textbox/inputbox was already restricted to characters and automatically add commas. It also has buttons with specific amount that totals itself every 'amount button' clicked. But if the customer wants to type the amount it should restrict non-whole amount (10009).

```
<input type="number" class="input-char-amo" id="total" step="10000" value="0" min='10000' max="5000000" onkeypress="return CheckNumeric()" onkeyup="FormatCurrency(this)" (using document.getElementById("id").value) / required>
```

https://codepen.io/Cilissaaa/pen/OJJXXrJ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use an input of type number you can set the `step` property:

```html
<input type="number" step="1000" value="0" min="0" />
```

Comment: This seems close. Thank you! But Is it also possible if it has automatically add comma and restrict negative amount?

Comment: Yes, you can exclude negative numbers with `min`. But you should always be careful with manipulating fields while the user is typing, that might destroy usability in some cases.

Comment: Thank you so much! I already edited my codes with your answer but I also need to let the customer type their amount and convert/change the typed amount into nearest whole numbers. I edited my post so you can check what I'm trying to solve. Feel free to correct if there's unnecessary  codes.

Comment: I want to ask one more thing. Why is it If I try to type a number in the input field, it only allow 3 digits and when it is 4 digits it automatically clear all?

Comment: don't know. Browser specific behaviour

Answer (score 1):

Rather than explicitly setting for each value you can optimize it by using one function call.

```js
function showOutput(){
    var input = 520007;
    var finVal
    var dividend=10;
    if(input % 10 !==0) {
   let len = (''+input).length;
 for(let i=1;i<len-1;i++){
     dividend=dividend*10;
 }
 let firstDigit=(input/dividend).toString().split(".")[0];
 console.log(firstDigit)
 finVal=dividend*firstDigit;
 console.log(finVal)
    }else{
        console.log(input)
    }
         
    }

    showOutput()
```

> This is the function where input will be from textBox (using document.getElementById("id").value) and it checks where it is divisible by 10 or not if not, it will in the for loop find the number of digit ,prepare the 0's to get appended and then find the first digit of the number.

Answer (score -1):

Please try this on your code :

```js
function showOutput(){
var output = document.getElementById("num").value
var finVal

if(output >= 1000 && output <= 1999) {
finVal = 1000
}
else if(output >= 2000 && output <= 2999){
finVal = 2000
}
else{
finVal = 0
}
alert(finVal)

}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="num"/>
<input type="button" onClick="showOutput()" value ="TEST" /> 
<label id="outputHere">
```

Comment: Is it possible if I'm trying to display the changed amount/automatic changed amount in inputbox also?

Comment: Yes of course. This is just one of the simplest ways how to resolve your problem. You should specify your parameters.

Comment: This works, but the code is very bad. This would end up being a function with a massive amount of lines and would become completely unmaintainable. Don't  use this approach in a professional environment.